# Detecting blinking light on a device

Tags: python, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision, opencv

Can anyone tell me good approaches to detect blinking light in a video? The background may change constantly. As of now,  the color would remain same but the intensity and angle of vision can change. There can be multiple glowing lights too but I want to identify only the blinking one.

My approach till now: 
Used a high density mask to retain only the blinking flash light and then observe the change in intensity over a time frame,  but unfortunately the noise in non blinking videos are so much that they too are being classified as blinking. 
As of now,   I am going to train on more data.  Can you think of any other approach? Rule based also is okay to me.

Comment: Very interesting question. Are you doing some sort of "time series" during your picture comparison. In other words, how are you detecting that a light is now blinking versus one that has always been on or has just gone from on-to-off? You would have to have some element of a short-term comparison between two time periods to detect that, no?

Comment: Kinda mixed.  I have solved the above problem (but it's all work around and it's taking 7.7seconds to process). Right now,  I am actually making a graph with intensity change over a time,  saving that image and then using a CNN based classifier to classify  blinking and non blinking graphs. Anything shorter and more robust can be applied?